# RabbitMQ Clustering with SSL

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, cluster-analysis

I have set up RabbitMQ on two different servers, rabbitmq@nodes1 and rabbitmq@nodes2. I have successfully configured SSL connection to the management interface of my RabbitMQ instances and also secured their AMQP connections with SSL. I have combined these two RabbitMQ instances into a cluster, but I want this cluster to operate with SSL. Below, I am sharing my rabbitmq.config file and the listening section from the management interface. Could you please advise on which setting in my config file I can use to enable SSL for my RabbitMQ cluster?

```
Listening ports
Protocol    Node    Bound to    Port
amqp/ssl    rabbit@nodes1   ::  5671
amqp/ssl    rabbit@nodes2   ::  5671
clustering  rabbit@nodes1   ::  25672
clustering  rabbit@nodes2   ::  25672
https   rabbit@nodes1   ::  15671
https   rabbit@nodes2   ::  15671
```

```
loopback_users = none

listeners.tcp = none

management.ssl.port       = 15671
management.ssl.cacertfile = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-CA-certificata.pem
management.ssl.certfile   = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-server-cert.pem
management.ssl.keyfile    = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-serverpemkeyfile.pem

management.ssl.versions.1 = tlsv1.3


listeners.ssl.default = 5671
ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-CA-certificata.pem
ssl_options.certfile = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-server-cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = /etc/pki/tls/RMQ-serverpemkeyfile.pem
ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true

management.ssl.ciphers.1 = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I am trying to do

```
Listening ports
Protocol    Node    Bound to    Port
amqp/ssl    rabbit@nodes1   ::  5671
amqp/ssl    rabbit@nodes2   ::  5671
clustering/ssl  rabbit@nodes1   ::  25671
clustering/ssl  rabbit@nodes2   ::  25671
https   rabbit@nodes1   ::  15671
https   rabbit@nodes2   ::  15671
```